# Swift debugging generic type variables

Tags: xcode, swift, debugging, generics

I'm trying out generics in swift an came across something unusual while debugging:
instead of printing out the value assigned to the variable, it just prints something different. Heres the example code:

```
class GenericExample<T: Comparable>{
    var someVar: T

    init(myVar: T){
       someVar = myVar
    }
}

let generics = GenericExample<Int>(myVar: 57)
print(generics.someVar)
```

the result is fine(57) but when running the program for debugging, as in with breakpoints, the value is presented as something like 4301684792

any tips would be appreciated

Comment: i forgot to mention this started happening after updating to Xcode 7.1

Comment: There's no reason at all that `someVar` should be implicitly unwrapped.  It should either be optional or non-optional.

Comment: whoops you're right, thanks for pointing it out. but the issue with the debugger still remains

Comment: I'm not seeing this. Prints 57 in Xcode 7.1 (7B91b). Is this your actual test code?

Comment: printing works fine, but when adding a breakpoint to check the value currently stored i get a random number

Comment: Sounds like you're adding the breakpoint before the value gets assigned, so you get a random value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't examine, in the debugger, the value of a variable whose value is not assigned until the line you're breakpointed in or later. That line has not been executed yet, so you will see a random value! (Namely, whatever happens to be sitting in memory at that address.)

Only examine *earlier* variable values! And don't even *look* at the little tooltips that pop up. Look only at the variables pane and the `lldb` console.

Comment: what it i place the breakpoint at the `print(generics.someVar)` line. Isn't the value already assigned at this point?

Comment: isn't _someVar_ already containing a value after the `let generics = GenericExample<Int>(myVar: 57)`

Comment: There is no `someVar` in this context. It is local elsewhere. It has gone out of scope. You're being misled by the tooltips. Don't look at them! You clearly don't understand when they are valid and when they aren't.